# Script to Rename files with a Date suffix to a common filename

Tags: bash

I have a requirement where I need to rename a couple of filenames to a fixed filename every week.

To explain better, each week I receive 3 files  in the format :

```
File_ABC_20160822.TXT.pgp
File_DEF_20160822.TXT.pgp
File_GHI_20160822.TXT.pgp
```

I need to run a small script to rename the files to :

```
File_ABC.dat
File_DEF.dat
File_GHI.dat
```

without deleting the original files, since we have to keep a log of delivered files.

The issue is that since the files come with a new date suffix each week, the script would have to pick current system date in YYYYMMDD format.

Comment: Need the script to run in UNIX environment

Comment: If you want "without deleting the original files", then you want to **copy** the file File_ABC_20160822.TXT.pgp to File_ABC.dat, right? Use `cp` and not `mv`. Good luck.

Comment: When posting on SO you should specify what you've tried and what didn't work, not only what you need..

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the files names use `bash` parameter expansion to get the desired name while renaming:

```
for f in File_*_*.TXT.pgp; do echo cp -i "$f" "${f%_*}.dat"; done
```

The above will do a Dry-run, for actual action, remove `echo`:

```
for f in File_*_*.TXT.pgp; do cp -i "$f" "${f%_*}.dat"; done
```

Comment: I'd use `cp`, because of "without deleting the original files".